# Using Cuckoo with Swift, why is the call to `stub` complaining that the class from GeneratedMocks doesn't conform to Mock protocol?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking

Using Cuckoo 1.4.1, I get the error

```
Global function 'stub(_:block:)' requires that 'DeepFileManager' conform to 'Mock'
```

I don't know how to proceed, because the instance passed to the `stub` function was created from the class in `GeneratedMocks.swift`. The reference to `DeepFileManager` is the class that is mocked.

So it's a mystery to me why Swift 4 would complain about the conformance of the superclass of the instance I've passed to it. Can you lead me out of this conundrum?

Here's the code for the test:

```swift
class RecordingTests: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        let FAKE_ID = "String";
        let mockFileManager: MockDeepFileManager = MockDeepFileManager()
        let cut = Recording(id: FAKE_ID, date: nil, status: nil, device: nil, deviceId: nil, deviceName: nil, fileManager: mockFileManager)
        describe("A recording") {
            context("when it's not on disk") {
                it("responds that filePresent is false") {
                    stub(mockFileManager) {stub in
                        when(stub.fileExists(audioId: FAKE_ID)).then()
                    }
                    expect(cut.filePresent()).to(equal(false))
                    verify(mockFileManager).fileExists(audioId: "Matchable")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the declaration of `MockDeepFileManager` from `GeneratedMocks.swift`:

```swift
 class MockDeepFileManager: DeepFileManager, Cuckoo.ClassMock {
```

Comment: I raised this problem as [an issue with the package](https://github.com/Brightify/Cuckoo/issues/377), but the responses from the developers haven't yielded a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment, an issue was submitted against the package, and the [response explains](https://github.com/Brightify/Cuckoo/issues/377#issuecomment-805629335) how to make it work.

The problem in the code was calling `then()` (with no arguments), as `then` requires a closure function with a signature to match the signature of the stubbed function. A simpler alternative that would achieve the aim is `thenReturn` (instead of `then`), which just needs a value of the type of the stubbed function's return.

The maintainer of the Cuckoo package expressed sympathy that Swift issues an error about the protocol, instead pointing to the error in the invocation of `then`.